# Make the Winter Bash icon render earlier

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2017

I have the habit of refreshing pages very often. As such, I very much notice the flicker that is caused by the delayed addition of the Winter Bash icon:

[image: Delayed addition of the Winterbash icon when refreshing the page]

Is there anything you can do to make this happen *earlier*, so the flicker isn’t so apparent?

Comment: Disable hats...?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Disabling hats only disables the hat rendering on the site but the icon is still being added there (to reenable it). Also, I would rather do the opposite: Keep hats enabled but remove that icon ^^"

Comment: Huh, so hats even haunt you if you explicitly hate them!

Comment: You always have custom CSS if you really want it gone (Stylish and others) (`.icon-winterbash {
    display: none !important;
}`)

Comment: Whilst refreshing the page, blink.

Comment: *Make the Winter Bash icon appear earlier* - would February be early enough? :p

Comment: @Jon pff! :P Fixed the title to make it clearer for you.

Comment: On MSE: [Don't move all the cheese for this snowflake](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304516/dont-move-all-the-cheese-for-this-snowflake)

Comment: You certainly need a faster cpu! 

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt How fast, exactly? I see the flicker even on [my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1nhH.png). I guess I don't meet the top bar's system requirements either.

Comment: This has nothing to do with CPU speed. The problem is that the script is loaded asynchronously *using AJAX* but only *after* all the rest of the scripting environment has already been set up. If this was a normal script include, the browser could run this a lot earlier and the flicker likely wouldn’t appear at all.

Comment: **Fix it**. This is the one hundred and eleventh time I clicked on reviews queue icon. I don't want to click on reviews queue icon. I need to see my rep.