# Winter Bash icon breaks muscle memory

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

[Related to this question, but not the same.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360713/make-the-winter-bash-icon-render-earlier)

The Winter Bash icon, aside from being annoying frippery, breaks muscle memory for those who are used to clicking on a particular area of the screen to access the functions of the site that are actually useful.

This is exacerbated by the fact that, as the linked question notes, the WB icon only shows up a few seconds after the page has loaded. What this means is that I load the SO main page, move my cursor to click on "Review queues", and by the time I click the WB icon has shifted the queues to the left, so I end up clicking on WB. Go go gadget usability!

I know that asking for the most simple and logical solution, like "allow a user to permanently disable this Winter Bash BS", is an impossibly complicated feature for SO to implement, so instead of doing that I'm opening the floor to discussion of how this should be fixed.

That way the community can come to an optimal solution, which SO's development team will never implement, so nobody wins.

**Edit: for everyone who downvoted/flagged this for deletion, please have a look at my [question history on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/70345/ian-kemp?tab=questions), particularly regarding review queues - it will hopefully help you to understand the reasons for my negative tone and frustration.**

Comment: Understandable, have a great day.

Comment: In your browser devtools, your adblocker, your firewall or whatever, block requests to `https://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/js/wb-core-incl.js` and you're cruising. The reason it "pops in" like that is because it's added dynamically with JS and not part of the pre-rendered DOM and so it can be blocked rather easily. Could SO have done this server-side? Sure, but it's really only a short period each year this is a problem so it's not a big deal in my opinion.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1172/

But I actually think you made a good point here.

Comment: Can't WB be disabled with the "I hate hats" link?

Comment: @ivarni Thanks, I am aware of those workarounds, but my point is that I shouldn't have to apply them.

Comment: @yivi No, there is no option to disable it permanently. Clicking "I hate hats" just changes the button back to a "give me hats" one - another basic usability failure.

Comment: So you don't want to fix it on your end and you're saying SO won't fix it on theirs so what exactly is the point of this post then? Is it just to complain and gripe?

Comment: I didn't know. Still, tempest in a teapot, IMO. The "I shouldn't have to do X" argument doesn't hold water from where I'm sitting. We are not entitled to X or Y feature or UI just because we want it. And your post doesn't seem overly constructive. You are already aware of the workarounds, and do not believe SO will do anything else this... so your point is?

Comment: @ivarni yivi If the damn stupid icon had never been added, there would never have been a problem. SO created this problem, they should fix it. I know they won't, because the company no longer cares about anything except monetization and adding "features" that nobody wants - but that doesn't mean I'm going to stop holding them accountable.

Comment: Well in that case, have a great day. Sorry you wasted my time.

Comment: You got the wrong [room](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDjCqjzbvJY). This one is "argument", but you are looking for "abuse".

Comment: Perhaps a decent feature request might be to move the _give me hats_ button to the user profile, instead of leaving it in the top bar. That way, all the grumpy people will be less confronted with all the hat fun (and it also fixes the related question with the blinking)

Comment: Amazing display of haughtiness and superiority by so many commenters. the OP makes TWO valid points, gets set upon in response for "being uncool". Brings back memories long since repressed ...

Comment: You are being punished for actually trying to improve the site by having developed ***a habit*** of going to the review queues in the first place! --- "few seconds" seems very long time, for me it's more like 0.3 secs, the jerking to the left comes right away, it's barely noticeable. (0.5s on first load, much less on subsequent refresh)

Comment: @Will How are they being punished??

Comment: @WillNess what about being constructive and not ranting at first, the fact it is not downvoted showcase there's truth, but the format of the post itself makes it useless.

Comment: @yivi the OP has developed a ***habit*** of going to review queues, now it jerks right from their thumb, makes them chase it. that's how.

Comment: They are being confrontational and argumentative without any attempt at being constructive. Being criticized is **not** being punished.

Comment: @Tensibai yes they are downvoted. it's +6 / -6 right now.

Comment: So what if they are down-voted? Down votes are no punishment, are expressions of opinion; which is the whole point of posting there in the first place.

Comment: @yivi I was merely informing a person of the facts they seemed unaware of.

Comment: @WillNess well, I should have said 0 scored instead right. the point stands, it would be positively scored if not ranting all way down but really asking for a fix in good faith.

Comment: @Tensibai "ranting" is hurtful superior language.

Comment: It's not. It's an opinion, with solid base on reality. Have you read the post and subsequent comments?

Comment: @WillNess blame me not being a native english speaker, ranting means 'not constructive, only criticizing' in my mind.

Comment: @Tensibai how can a complaint be brought up without describing the nature of the problem? the few last sentences have no bearing on the complaint's content. which is perfectly valid and legit. the OP's strong feelings about lack of positive response - perceived by them - from SO team, I assume, is based on some past I'm not aware of. Unless I'm willing to investigate the specifics of that past (I'm not) I'm not going to just assume they are being unreasonable; I'll just ignore that part and concentrate on the substance of their complaint.

Comment: @WillNess Why does a complain should be negative in advance on the result ? There's no reason, I'll stop feeding the troll now, there's nothing to salvage here as the OP has already dismissed willing to ask for a solution.

Comment: Will, the user's past experience is not relevant to the post. Content in the network is evaluated on its own merit. They user **is** ranting. It doesn't matter if they believe if it is justified. Ranting does not tend to be well received, logically. Besides, user may not particularly agree with the core of his complaint as well.

Comment: the OP feels strongly hurt by this issue, assumes for some reason they will be dismissed, naturally gets upset about having their feelings of hurt dismissed out of hand, complains a bit loudly, ***gets promptly dismissed!*** (and blamed for the dismissal itself). that about sums it up from my POV. :)

Comment: Adblock works just fine for your use case.

Comment: @WillNess: The OP was passive-aggressive / confrontational / unconstructive from the start. Just look at this: _"I know that asking for the most simple and logical solution, <...>, is an impossibly complicated feature for SO to implement <...> the community can come to an optimal solution, which SO's development team will never implement, so nobody wins."_

This isn't a feature request, this is a rant. That's why it's being dismissed. The OP isn't interested in taking _simple_ steps to avoid the issue. They expect SO to go out of their way to make something this insignificant configurable.

Comment: @Cerbrus I understand, but this is not the substance, only the wrapping. You may say it was a self-fulfilling prophecy, but that shouldn't happen IMO. If the OP got help with their issue, and got taken seriously on it, they'd naturally felt remorse for being prejudicial, would have apologized, and we'd be all better for it. Was it such a great insult? I don't think so. In any case the team / community could have taken it as an opportunity for proving them WRONG. And they unfortunately didn't. :)

Comment: and it never was a feature request. it was tagged as "discussion".

Comment: @WillNess: Why should the community take a "complaint" seriously if the OP goes out of their way to be passive-aggressive? ___Especially___ if the OP is just dismissing any and all valid solutions just because he doesn't want to do ___anything___ himself? The FR / Discussion semantic is irrelevant.

Comment: @Cerbrus maybe they don't ask for themselves, but just bring up a UX discrepancy? Some users might not know how to block the http requests...

Comment: @WillNess: What about the question makes you think this isn't about the OP? The fact he's mentioned muscle memory making him miss-click? Or the fact he mentioned not wanting to use any of the workarounds? Now you're reaching a bit...

Comment: @Cerbrus not *only* about them... what they experienced, there might be others like them, trying to make the site better on a daily basis so much that they even develop a habit of clicking on review queues icon right away - and being punished for it! Ironic, looks like it, to me; this. :)

Comment: That there _might_ be others that want this still doesn't mean this is a constructive discussion. That still doesn't mean this question shouldn't be closed. It's unconstructive.

Comment: @WillNess I tried being constructive in my first comment by tracking down the script that causes this and suggesting ways to block it. The OP made it clear they were not interested in any kind of solution, even if the entire issue can be solved in under 20 seconds from the clientside. Instead they clarified that they want *"to hold SO accountable"*. This post was never about finding a constructive solution.

Comment: Actually @ivarni, I already posted a constructive solution, which is to allow us to permanently opt-out of hats.

Comment: the guy uncovers major UX inconvenience, proposes the most reasonable - yes, the one that would probably take a lot of work from the SO team, adds few irrelevant grumblings. that about it. the response should be from the POV of "how do we make the site better?", not "did the asker come to us sufficiently humbled, cap in hand?"

Comment: @WillNess Yep of course, we should be allowed to be arrogant and snarky toward the provider and expect the provider to fulfill our request right now, immediately !!!!. Because we're users and being aggressive isn't a problem when you ask for something after all. The way you formulate a request is as important as the request itself. In brief you can _not_ expect respect and be taken seriously when you doesn't show any respect to your interlocutor.

Comment: @Tensibai this depends on your interlocutor's goals, isn't it. A mathematician's theorem is not invalidated by him being snarky and rude, as one example. And BTW I saw no arrogance in the questioner's remarks, more like desperation.

Comment: @WillNess You are correct. I'm desperate, sad, angry about the fact that Stack Overflow seems more and more focused on everything except upholding the quality of the site. I'm desperate, sad, angry that tiny, simple changes that would help the quality aren't made, while time and effort is instead expended on virtual hats. I'm desperate, sad, angry that Stack Overflow is killing itself and nobody seems to care; instead the same white knights show up again and again to defend the site's "honour", tell me I'm wrong and being mean, and that I should just be quiet and accept the status quo.

Comment: White knight reporting for duty: A silly little winter bash icon isn't going to kill this site.

Comment: **"These users are also a voting force: any meta proposal that tries to do something about the flagging quality of Q+A is quickly voted into the ground..."** ([Should trivial re-occurring questions really be answered?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/839601)) @WillNess that pretty much explains what we observe here doesn't it

Comment: @gnat: I feel the votes on here are more related to the tone of the question than the content. I think it'd have been received better if the tone was neutral.

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah tone, such a convenient smokescreen. It probably hurts delicate feelings of those who believe that this click-increasing event is so much more important than doing boring reviews

Comment: The new navigation bar layout completely fucked up both muscle memory and any possibility of visual recognition but nobody answered on that either.

Answer (score 0):

This has also caused me to mis-click more than once. (I don't mind Winterbash though.)

But, if you are a hat hater, it's super easy to fix with a [Stylish](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stylish/info) style:

```css
.icon-winterbash {display: none!important;}
```